# Unable to connect with the Windows desktop application using the Windows Sql Azure connection string?

Tags: sql-server, azure

we are using the window Azure first time and we have deplyed our SQL server databases on the window Sql Azure server. using the connection string from the SQL Azure server, we are able to successfully connect with the Web aapplication while at the same time when we are trying to connect with the Desktop application it always throw "General Network Error"?

In order to resolve the issue we have check the firewall and all seems to be fine.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

May I ask where your web application is running? It seems it is running in Windows Azure and connected to SQL Azure without any problem. Isnt it? I am always interested to know what tool you are using to connect? SSMS or SQLCMD or something else?

IF you want to connect SQL Azure from on premise (from your desktop) you really need to add your IP address in SQL Azure firewall exception list first. Even when you checked it that could be the main reason. Here is the [guideline connecting  SQL Azure DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx) and please follow first 3 points when you are trying to connect from your desktop. Those 3 points are:

1. Add your IP address in SQL Azure Exception List and add 1433 Port exception in your own firewall exception list
2. Verify you have setup firewall exception correctly
3. Always use  login1@servername when connecting to SQL Azure DB nane XXXX.database.windows.net

After that try using SqlCmd as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336280.aspx).